# Variable selection with right-censored data?

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection, lasso, censoring

I have the typical linear regression model:

$$y_i = x_i^T\beta + e_i,$$
where $e_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, iid. However, in my case, *some* (not all of them, only around 1/3 of them) response variables $y_i$ are right-censored. As far as I understand, I cannot apply LASSO (R package `lars`) directly. What alternative methods (I would be interested in a LASSO-type method) are there for selecting variables with right-censored outcomes? If they are implemented in R, much better.

Comment: How exactly are you estimating $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$?

Comment: @whuber I am estimating them using Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

Comment: @Neph did you ever find an answer to this?